# Is it possible to edit Textboxes in a browser using VIM or a VIM-Style-Editor?

Tags: browser, vim

Is it possible to edit Textboxes in a browser using VIM or a VIM-Style-Editor?

(On Ubuntu of course)

Comment: If you posted that as an answer, and showed a screenshot; I would definitely accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind having a second window opening, the right option is [It's all text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) extension. I have it configured to use `gVim`, and when a TEXTAREA appears, you can see a little button under it and clicking on it will let you use your favorite editor.

[image]

Comment: The question was about textboxes (a one-line fields), but “It’s all text” seems to support textareas only.

Comment: Also, unlike Pentadactyl, it does not lock textareas in browser while external editor is opened. Combined with the facts that: a) textarea is updated when *file was saved* (not when the editor is closed); b) edits applied by ”It’s all text” *does not stored* in undo memory of Firefox; it may lead to loosing of what you’ve written if you eventually would forget about launched external editor, which makes autosaves, and type something in textarea.

Comment: This is the solution I used; I like it because you can save a copy on to your desktop quite easily.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understoond, any browser suits you. So I would recommend you [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/) – an extension for Firefox. Besides vi-like keybindings for browsing / navigation and lots of attendant features, it also provides both possibilities, you’ve asked.

- External editor for textareas and textboxes, which is GVim by default, can be launched by `<C-i>`.
- Basic internal vi-style editor (so called ‘Text edit’ mode) is available by pressing `<C-t>` or can be configured to start directly when textarea / textbox is focused by `:set noinsertmode`. Unfortunately, it seems to be unmaintained now and therefore has several important issues which unlikely to be fixed. For instance it handles non-ASCII characters (like `ä`, `п`) improperly while doing word-movements (`w`, `e`, `b`, etc).

(Both hotkeys can be remapped of course.)

Comment: By the way, I wonder why Pentadactyl was removed from Ubuntu repository while it still present in Debian (as `xul-ext-pentadactyl`).